# php reading and plotting large datasets

Tags: php, web, plot

I have 5 second data for a year in an ascii file

each line is a reading...
timestamp, value

for 6 million lines

I want to display this data in a chart or multiple charts in a web browser

I considered a choice of 3 charts

1 - last 500 data points at maximum (5 second resolution)
2 - last 500 points at 15 min resolution
3 - all data at various resolutions
etc
being wary of a) time to read file b) processing time c) amount and time to download data to browser for javascript plotting

Can php do direct access read from a file?

More to the point, these big dataset plotting problems must be quite common, bhoiw do people get around it?

Comment: I suspect most people use indexed database systems rather than flat files: PHP can seek byte offsets within a file, but not individual lines without looping and counting

Answer (score 0):

Yes, PHP can [read files](https://www.php.net/fread) on the filesystem. Databases may be very helpful along with reading data from file with PHP.

What would you like to do with the data - as in, what are you really looking for? Are you looking for peaks, averages, values greater than average etc.?

### Generic analysis

Perhaps the answer is - I don't know; I want to look at the data and see what comes glaring out. Fair enough. In that case you could have a web page that uses something like a [stock chart](http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/). Show the last 1000 records.

To get the last 1000 records, you could use a combination of commands such as `top` or `head` (on Linux-y systems) or `powershell` on Windows to get last 1000 rows and then parse them with PHP, shove them into an array or object and show them on screen using Javascript or PHP charting tools.

When the user changes selection, do a read of the file and display relevant records. This can be taxing because the file is constantly processed.

#### Non-PHP method

A faster non-PHP alternate would be to use something like an in-memory business intelligence tool like [QlikView](http://www.qlikview.com/) (free download for personal use, I think). The learning curve is not steep, ... and I have no affiliation with QlikView. Tableau and Spotfire are other tools that can be easy to use and can make analysis of large datasets relatively easy.

### Specific analysis

If your interest is to find out number of days each month with sales of $1 million or above, you could do a single pass on the file and extract all lines with sales >= 1MM and store it in an array of date and sales. Pass through the array and output a file with Year, Month, Sales. That would be pre-processing of the data.

Then, the web application or your presentation layer can pull this data and show information in bar charts or whatever else. Javascript charting libraries like amcharts, d3, highcharts etc. can be used, or PHP charting libraries like jpGraph and such can be used to read pre-processed data on the fly and show them.

If data has to be looked from multiple angles such as - table showing top 10 products that are sold, scatter plot of # of orders vs. $ ordered etc., all this data could be shoved into a database and then pulled on the screen. As Mark Baker commented, appropriate indexes will be necessary to pull data efficiently.

### Prepare specific datasets in batch

Some climate research centers in the US run programs that churn through millions of records, like you have, at night to create graphs, charts, maps etc. and then use web applications to display them. For example [High Plains Regional Climate Center](http://www.hprcc.unl.edu/awdn/maps/index.php?product=Soil&type=&day=7d&action=viewmap) and [Iowa Mesonet](http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/timemachine/#1.201401101700) do that regularly. You could do something similar with PHP.

Databases are my favorite. I prefer massaging textual data, eliminate what I don't want and push the objective matter in databases. PHP can then utilize rollup, top n, group by etc. methods within dbs to extract data and present it on screen - primarily through a web interface.

If you have specific questions about toolset or so relevant to this question, feel free to comment. If a new question crops up in your mind, feel free to add a new question altogether to solicit diverse answers.